# GCC compile to assembly: cmp followed by call instead of conditional jump

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86

Is this assembly code reasonable?

```
cmp op1, op2
pushf
call _func
popf
jz .L0
```

I am wondering under what circumstances that GCC *as* can generate such code that *cmp* is followed by *call* instead of conditional jump

Comment: Have you seen gcc generate such code?  If so, from what source code?  It's "reasonable" in the sense that it would work, but I can't say I've seen such a construct in compiler output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, GCC would never do that, it would always use `setz bl` or something (in a call-preserved register) if it wanted to materialize a boolean now for use after a call.  Or just make sure both args to `cmp` would be available after the call and do or redo the compare then.

Either of these would be much cheaper; `popf` is quite slow because it can modify FLAGS like AC, and (in kernel mode) FLAGS like IF.  It needs conditional behaviour depending on CPU mode.  It's microcoded as many uops.   (Check instruction tables at https://agner.org/optimize/).  Like 7 on Skylake-X, with a throughput of one per 21 cycles (https://uops.info).

If a human programmer really wanted to save / restore multiple FLAGS including ZF, they'd use `lahf` / `mov ebx, eax` or something.  I don't think GCC tends to do that either.

GCC never uses push/pop around a call to save/restore something.  It reserves space at the top of the function and saves any call-preserved registers it wants to use.  To spill something to memory before a call, it would use `mov`, not push.

GCC only uses push before a call to pass stack args.  But we can rule that out for your example (and assume `call _func` takes no stack args) because functions own their stack args.  So if `pushf` had been passing an arg, `popf` would be popping potential garbage that `_func` could have stepped on.

Comment: **it would always use setz bl or something (in a call-preserved register) if it wanted to materialize a boolean now for use after a call.** Then GCC would have to do test %bl, %bl to make a jump, right? This would still do extra work than just put **cmp op1, op2** after **call**.

Comment: @syacer: yes, if op1 and op2 are easy to preserve, just doing the compare later is better.  If they were register values loaded from globals (that the function might modify), GCC would need to invent temporaries to save them.  Depending on register pressure, that saving copies in call-preserved registers that might be worse.  And even if there were spare 2 registers gcc could save/restore, GCC might still choose the most straightforward way and just save the boolean result.  Note that `test / jnz` is about the same cost as `jnz`, except for code-size, thanks for macro-fusion.

Comment: @syacer One thing you have to keep in mind is that `pushf` and `popf` are pretty slow instructions.  A compiler would never use these just to preserve the condition flags when it can do otherwise.

Comment: @fuz: The comment you're replying to is saying the alternative is to move `cmp` itself after the `call`.  That avoids the need for `pushf`/`popf`.  So yes, the @ syacer is correct, doing the `cmp` later is the best option.